# facebook events are not deduplicated

Tags: facebook, facebook-conversions-api

I sent 2 events. one via fbp and one via conversion api. I specified the event name and an event_id for both capi and fbp have the same event_id and event_name. but in the eventsmanaer both events are processed and none are deduplicated. what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance